# Did Umar have more than four wives after Muhammad revealed the restriction on men to having at most four?

Tags: nikah, sunni, sahaba

Is it true according to sunnis that [Hazrat Umar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umar) (R.A.) married daughter of [Hazrat Ali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali) (R.A.) after Muhammad's (S.A.W.) death?
 I think this is contradictory because at time of prophet's death Hazrat Umar had more than four wives, and prophet had restricted for all to a limit of four, although if they had more than four at that time, then it was allowed to carry on.
 So how is it possible that Hazrat Umar married after the restriction?

Comment: Could you show us some reference that he had more than 4 wifes at same time?

Comment: @Kilise I want to know wether or not he married more even after prophets death? As far as I know a man can't marry more than 4 at same time or different time.

Comment: Please add references for your question.

Comment: @Kilise So you want to say man can marry more than 4 at different time, like marrying 4 divorcing anyone and marrying another and so on? Wikipedia says :Umar married nine women in his lifetime and had fourteen children: ten sons and four daughters.

Comment: @Kilise so a man can marry more than 4 at different times?

Comment: No. If I am married now to 4, then i divorce one, and marry one more, i still am married to 4. and total i have been married to 5.. but only max 4 at the same time.

Comment: @Kilise any reference please?

Comment: Do you have any references against it? The default rule is that something is legal unless you prove it forbidden.

Comment: Logically, you can apply this to only one wife. In Europe, you are only able to marry ONE at time. If you divorce, you are free to marry another. So that would mean you have been married 2 times at total. It's the same thing, but just a higher number. Now of course when and who may marry more than one is another subject.

Answer (score 2):

After the revelation of verse [4:3](http://legacy.quran.com/4/3)

> ...  then marry those that please you of [other] women, two or three or four. ...

None of the sahaba had more than four wives as even those who converted later have been asked to divorce or separate from the rest of their allowed wives as you may read [here](http://sunnah.com/urn/512370) and [here](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/13/67).

Note that this verse is to be understood in having at most four wives at once not having four wives in the whole life (See [here](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=718&Itemid=59) in tafsir ibn Kathir)!

Now let's take a look at the wives of 'Omar:

1. Quraybah bint abi Omayya was his wife in Jahilya until the revelation of [60:10](http://legacy.quran.com/60/10) as she didn't convert to Islam he divorced her.
2. Um Kalthom bint Jarwal was also his wife in Jahiliya and divorced after the revelation of 60:10

   > ... And hold not to marriage bonds with disbelieving women ...
3. Zaynab bint Madh'oon was also his wife in Jahilya but converted with him to Islam. She's the mother of his son Abdullah and Hafsa whom became the wife of the Prophet.
4. Jamila bint Thabit he married her in the year 7 a.H. and she got divorced and later married Zayd ibn Thabit.
5. 'Atikah bint Zayd she was the former wife of  Abdullah ibn abi Bakr and after 'Omar's death she married a-Zubayr ibn al-'Awwam.
6. Um Hakim bint al-Harith she was the former wife of 'Ikrimah ibn abi Jahl and Khalid ibn Sa'id ibn al-'Aas.
7. Um Kalthoum bint 'Ali ibn Abi Talib was a young girl and got married to him in the year 17 a.H. and stayed in his household until he was killed.

So we can conclude that even if 'Omar has married -during his lifetime- in the whole seven wives he never had more than four wives at once.

Comment: If you read my comments to his question you might come to notice that he more likely mean that marrying 4 maximum and not only as once.