# Did Hazrat Abu Bakar had 5 wives?

Tags: wife, abu-bakr

While watching one Islamic short reel on Instagram, I saw a reel where it said that Hazrat Abu Bakar had 5 wives. Is this true? If yes, then what about the 4 wives rule?

Comment: Probably means in total, not at the same time.

Comment: @TheZ, do we have any authentic sources for the wives of Hazrat Abu Bakar?

Answer (score 2):

Before the qur'an decreed a limit some sahabah had even 9 wives and after the decree they needed to divorce some of their wives.
Allah the Almighty says:

> And if you fear that you will not deal justly with the orphan girls, then marry those that please you of [other] women, two or three or four. ... ([4:3](https://legacy.quran.com/4/3))

Also limiting the amount to 4 does only mean one cannot have more than 4 wives at once, but one may have married a lot more during his lifetime.

Further, all the biographies only mention four wives of abu Bakr which are agreed upon during his lifetime and those are:

1. [Qutaylah bint 'abd al-'Uzza](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Qutaylah_bint_Abd_al-Uzza&oldid=1140554125) قتيلة بنت عبد العزى the mother of 'Abdullah and Asama', it is disputed whether she ever converted to Islam. Abu Bakr already had divorced her in the pre-islamic era (al-Jahilyyah).
2. [Umm Ruman](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Umm_Ruman&oldid=1198680949), the mother of 'Aishah and 'Abdurrahman, she died in the year 4 or 5 a.H..
3. [Asma' bint 'Umais](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Asma_bint_Umais&oldid=1202403464) أسماء بنت عميس, she's the mother of his Son Muhammad, she was married before that with Ja'afar ibn abi Talib and after the death of abu Bakr to 'Ali ibn abi Talib.
4. Habibah bint Kharajah حبيبة بنت خارجة she gave birth to his daughter Umm Kalthum shortly after his death. She is from the tribe of Khazraj and her marriage was after the Hijra.

So we can already count and conclude that abu Bakr hardly had more than three of these wives at once.

As for the fifth wive she was mentioned in a hadith in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3921) where she is referred to as Umm Bakr:

> Narrate Aisha:
> **Abu Bakr married a woman from the tribe of Bani Kalb**, called **Um Bakr**. When **Abu Bakr migrated to Medina, he divorced her and she was married by her cousin**, the poet who said the following poem lamenting the infidels of Quraish: "What is there kept in the well, The well of Badr, (The owners of) the trays of Roasted camel humps? What is there kept in the well, The well of Badr, (The owners of) lady singers And friends of the honorable companions; who used to drink (wine) together, Um Bakr greets us With the greeting of peace, But can I find peace After my people have gone? The Apostle tells us that We shall live again, But what sort of life will owls and skulls live?

As we can see abu Bakr never had more than four wives at once.

See also: [Did Umar have more than four wives after Muhammad revealed the restriction on men to having at most four?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35335/did-umar-have-more-than-four-wives-after-muhammad-revealed-the-restriction-on-me)

Answer (score 1):

The rule regarding having four wives is that one can be concurrently married to four women. This doesn't imply a limit on the number of times one can marry throughout their entire life. Abu Bakr divorced [Qutaylah bint Abd al-Uzza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qutaylah_bint_Abd_al-Uzza) during the pre-Islamic era and married [Asma bint Umais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asma_bint_Umais) after she became widowed following the battle of Mu'tah. Therefore, he wasn't simultaneously married to them.